# Appending an element once to a sibling element using onclick and parents

Tags: jquery

What I'm trying (poorly) to do is to hide an element when it is clicked, and append some text to the body element above it. I was able to successfully target the parent div, add a class of clicked, then target the siblings of that div to append the new div and its subsequent text to it. The issue is that, with several of these parent divs living on screen, when I click the element within the other divs on the page, it adds another appended 'content' div to the divs before it. It is quite possible I'm doing this in the most inefficient way I can be; my Javascript skills are lacking...

```
    var link = $('.is-useful-link a');
    var unclicked = $('.field-name-field-review-useful');


    link.click(function(){
        $(this).parents('.field-name-field-review-useful').addClass('clicked');
        if (unclicked.hasClass('clicked')) {

            var $clicked = $('.field-name-field-review-useful.clicked');
            var content = '<div class="thanks animated fadeIn">Thanks for your feedback!</div>';

            $clicked.hide();
            $clicked.siblings('.field-name-body')
                .append(content);

        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the first time you click a `link`, it gives `field-name-field-review-useful` a class of `clicked`. Then you're checking if `field-name-field-review-useful` has the `clicked` class, and if it has, append the `content`.

The second time you click a `link`, the same thing happens, except you now have two elements with the `field-name-field-review-useful` class, so it appends the content to it again.

I'd suggest that you attach the click handler using [`one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/), that way, the click handler will only fire once per element (please note, the below is untested):

```
link.one('click', function() {
  $(this).parents('.field-name-field-review-useful')
         .addClass('clicked') // do you need this anymore?
         .hide()
         .siblings('.field-name-body').append(content);       
});
```

Note: I've made an assumption that `.field-name-field-review-useful` only has one siblings with the class `.field-name-body`, if that's not the case, then you'll see the same behaviour as before (content being appended to multiple `.field-name-body's`). If that is the case, you'd have to restructure your markup, or use some other traversal methods to get  so that you can get the relevant `.field-name-body`.

Comment: I did not need the .addClass functionality using the above code. This worked marvelously. Thanks so much, Billy.